# cq5 - livecopy - how to tell when a page is a live copy and finding the children of its parents

Tags: aem

Our setup has various websites and some of which are livecopies from the main site. We are trying to determine if the page we are on is a livecopy. If so try and get its parent and the children of the parents. This allows us to determine each pages siblings to then use how we want.

Is this easily achievable using cq?

Comment: I presume you mean programmatically? What version of CQ are you using btw?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Checking if the page is a live copy**

You can use [`LiveRelationshipManager`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/msm/api/LiveRelationshipManager.html), adaptable from resource resolver:

```
resourceResolver.adaptTo(LiveRelationshipManager.class)
```

It has method [`hasLiveRelationship`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/msm/api/LiveRelationshipManager.html#hasLiveRelationship%28org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource%29) which will return `true` if passed resource is a live copy of something other. You can invoke this method passing current component resource.

**Parent and siblings**

Use [`PageManager`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html) and [`Page`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html) methods:

```
// resource - current component resource
ResourceResolver resolver = resource.getResourceResolver();
PageManager pageManager = resolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
Page currentPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(resource);
Page parentPage = currentPage.getParent();
Iterator<Page> siblings = parentPage.listChildren();
```

Comment: Would these child pages themselves be the direct live copies of the parent? Or would I have to do some sort of manual check? Would prefer to find the parent page of a live copy page, and then find all live copy pages belonging to the parent.