# Adobe CQ. How to get blueprint page of a LiveCopy

Tags: java, adobe, aem, jcr

I have a page(`A`) which is a LiveCopy of another page(`B`), which is a LiveCopy of another Blueprint page(`C`). Some pages have longer hierarchy from a LiveCopy to a Blueprint page.

So how I can find Blueprint page of some LiveCopy page programmatically? I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871093/cq5-livecopy-how-to-tell-when-a-page-is-a-live-copy-and-finding-the-children) how to check if page is LiveCopy. But how to find her Blueprint page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd again use the [LiveRelationshipManager](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/msm/api/LiveRelationshipManager.html#getLiveRelationship(org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource,%20boolean)) that Tomek linked to in that answer.

First by calling `getLiveRelationship` & then asking the returned [LiveRelationship](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/msm/api/LiveRelationship.html) for its source:

```
Resource pageA; //LiveCopy of Page B;
LiveRelationshipManager liveRelationshipManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(LiveRelationshipManager.class);
PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);

LiveRelationship liveRelationship = liveRelationshipManager.getLiveRelationship(pageA, false);
String pageBPath = liveRelationship.getSourcePath();

Page pageB = pageManager.getPage(pageBPath);
```

The `false` on the `getLiveRelationship` method above refers to an "Advanced Status" — no reference to what this is according to the JavaDocs apart that it is *'time-consuming'* to compute.